# IONIC 3 - Improve image picker performance and sorting option

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-gallery, photo-gallery

I am developing an IONIC 3 application which is used to upload the images from gallery to server.

I have used the IONIC image picker plugin using the link below to achieve this.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker/

The plugin is working fine in the newest phones. I'm facing the performance issues in old phones.

The gallery is sorted from the oldest to the newest pictures. I need to list the images from newest to oldest.

Very low performance while opening the gallery. Took a very long time to open the gallery images and I could see the white screen when I tried to scroll the images.

Is the issue related to phone memory performance? Is there any workaround to fix these issues?

I'm using below code to open the gallery to get the images

```
let options = {
               maximumImagesCount: 5,
               quality: 50
               }

this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
   console.log(results)
}
```

Thanks in advance